# Making instance values equal

Tags: c#, equality

How to Make it True????

```
            Student studentInstance1 = new Student();
            Student studentInstance2 = new Student();
            studentInstance1.Name = "qwerty";
            studentInstance2.Name = "qwerty";
            if(studentInstance1==studentInstance2)
```

I need Answer how make that Instance Values equal???

Comment: Overload the `==` operator. (And `.Equals` too.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way will be to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods in your `Student` class. Here is a article in msdn how to do it: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173147%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from @DIneshBalan Mahendran you would need to overload the `==` operator. This is an example of comparing the two instances by name but you can extend it as much as you like.

```
public static bool operator ==(Student student1, Student student2)
{
   return student1.Name.Equals(student2.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool operator ==(Student a, Student b){
    return a.Name == b.Name;
}
public static bool operator !=(Student a, Student b){
    return !(a==b);
}
```

Note that in C#, you have to overload the `==` and `!=` operators simultaneously.

Comment: CounterExample: NullException when you try to compare with null, e.g. `Stundent a = new Student(); if (a == null)...`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to implement custom equality rules, you have to implement

```
  Equals
  GetHashCode
  == operator
  != operator
```

Something like that:

```
  public class Student {
    public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;

      Student other = obj as Student;

      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        return false;

      return String.Equals(Name, other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
      return String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static Boolean operator ==(Student left, Student right) {
      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        return true;
      else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, left) || 
               Object.ReferenceEquals(null, right))
        return false;

      return String.Equals(left.Name, right.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public static Boolean operator !=(Student left, Student right) {
      return !(left == right);
    }

    ...

    // You'd rather had Name being immutable: once assigned and neber changed
    public Student(String name) {
      Name = name;
      ...
    }

    // You'd rather had Name being immutable
    public String Name {
      get;
      private set;    
    }
  }
```

Yet *another* issue with `Name` property, it should be ***immutable***, just see:

```
  if (studentInstance1 == studentInstance2) {
    // From now studentInstance1 is not equal to studentInstance2 any more! 
    studentInstance1.Name = 'Some other name';

  ...

  Dictionary<Student, int> quizResults = new Dictionary<Student, int> {
    {studentInstance1, 90}
    {studentInstance2, 85}};

  studentInstance1.Name = 'Some other name';
  int result = quizResults[studentInstance1]; // <- Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare both object directly if they both are having same property then and only then it will return true.

Now here i am considering Student class has only one Name property.

For Ex.

```
Student Student1=new Student();
Student Student2=new Student();

Student1.Name="qwerty";
Student2.Name="qwerty";
```

So you can use:

```
bool bIsEqual=Student1.Equals(Student2);
```

And if you want to compare only strings you can also use :

```
bool bIsEqual=Student1.Name.Equals(Student2.Name, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```